# C++ Decimal to Hexadecimal (int to char)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a function that takes an `int` in as a parameter and returns a hexadecimal of type `char`. Here is the function:

```
char toHex(int dec)
{
    std::stringstream a;
    a << std::hex << dec;
    return a.str().c_str()[0];
}
```

It returns the hexidecimal version, but only the first digit, as I wrote the `[0]`. So if the hex value is `14` then I only get a `1`. Without this `[]` specification, it is an `std::string`, but I need the complete hexadecimal in `char` form.

I was thinking about making a for loop that replaces the 0 with a cycle so that it iterates through the first `i` characters, but I don't think there is a way to append regular characters (`char`) together. What should I do? Thanks!

Edit:
To be clear, I want to do this process as an example:
declare a `char` variable, `char h`, then convert the integer `104` to hex, which is `0x68`, then assign `0x68` to the variable `h` of type `char`

Comment: What do you mean with "I need the complete hexadecimal in char form."? Since you know how you get the value as `std::string` and how to get a `char` from it, I would think you know everything you want to know. What is your problem? What do you really want?

Comment: I want to be able to do this process (just example): declare a char variable, `char h`, then convert the integer `104` to hex, which is `0x68`, then assign `0x68` to the variable `h` of type `char`.

Comment: But you are already doing this. And since `char` is a character, you cannot assign multiple characters to it. You can convert `10` to `'A'` or `15` to `'F'`. It is also possible to convert `16` to `"10"`. But you cannot assign `"10"` to a character.

Comment: @ArchieGertsman:  The values inside variables are always in 2's-complement binary (base 2).  It's only when you print it out or save it in a string that you'd convert it to a hex representation.  `char h = 104;`  is the same thing as `char h = 0x68;` because both get stored as the same binary value in `h`.

Comment: Okay so if I had a spinbox return an `int` value of 15, it would equally return the value of `0x0F`?

Comment: @ArchieGertsman Yes, `15 == 0x0F` should be `true`. You are only writing the number to the variable. If you want to store a string, you have to use a type for strings.

Comment: @indiv `always in 2's-complement` No.

Answer (score 1):

A character can only hold... well, one character.  0-F would be one character in the case of a hex number.  When you have an array of characters (multiple characters), you have a string.  How could you possibly represent the decimal number 255, hex FF as a single character?

Comment: say I do this: `char h = 0x68; cout << h << endl;` I get the letter `h`. I need to take the decimal, convert its value to hex, adn save that hex value to type `char`. So it would go like this: `104 > 0x68 > assign 0x68 to a char variable`

Comment: @ArchieGertsman But you know that `0x68` is one number, and not two/three/four characters? And it's equal to 104. If that is really your goal, you don't even need to do anything.

Comment: Yes. But how do I convert an `int` to hex form and directly save that hex to a variable of type `char`?

Comment: @ArchieGertsman I'll say it again, a `int` has no "hex form" (neither hex nor decimal nor binary nor anything else). It's a invisible number, nothing else. If you really want 0x68, you don't need to do anything. It seems you want "0x68", but in your edit you're telling us it's not so. ... What now?

Answer (score 1):

A `char` can only represent a single character. If you need the whole string, the best thing to do would be to return the `std::string` created by the call to `a.str()`.

If you need to return a C-style string, then you need to return a `char *` (or `char const *`) that points to the storage location for the characters, at which point you need to manage its lifetime (which `std::string` does for you).